# Apache 2.4.7 redirect not working when multiple Virtual host tags are present Ubuntu14.04

Tags: apache, redirect, ssl, ubuntu-14.04, apache2.4

I have 2 virtual host tags in my conf file.

> 1st Tag contains the redirect rule for request coming through internal IP address.
>
> 2nd Tag contains the other redirect rules for request coming through public ip or any other place

**When I remove the first VirtualHost tag, redirect and ssl works perfectly fine, but I need the first VirtualHost tag as well**

### My conf file

this is located at /etc/apache2/sites-available/site.conf

```
<VirtualHost 10.1.0.7:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    LogLevel debug
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    ServerName servername.com
    ProxyPass /Service http://localhost:8080/Service
    ProxyPassReverse /Service http://localhost:8080/Service
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    LogLevel debug
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    ServerName servername.com
    RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L] 
</VirtualHost>
```

#### If I remove the first VirtualHost tag which contains the private IP, everything works fine, but as soon as I add it, the server does not redirect to 443 port.

### My ssl conf file:

located at /etc/apache2/sites-available/site-ssl.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    LogLevel debug
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
     ProxyPreserveHost On
        ServerName server.com
    # Redirections:
    ProxyPass /server-status http://localhost:7570/server-status
    ProxyPassReverse /server-status http://localhost:7570/server-status

    ProxyPass /mCare/subscribe ws://localhost:8080/mCare/subscribe
    ProxyPassReverse /mCare/subscribe ws://localhost:8080/mCare/subscribe

    ProxyPass /mCare http://localhost:8080/mCare
    ProxyPassReverse /mCare http://localhost:8080/mCare

    ProxyPass /solr http://localhost:8280/solr
    ProxyPassReverse /solr http://localhost:8280/solr

    SSLEngine on
            SSLCertificateFile      /mnt/opt/ssl/2015/sha2/b89516b0cdc9a701.crt
            SSLCertificateKeyFile   /mnt/opt/ssl/2015/sha2/mcare.pem
            SSLCertificateChainFile /mnt/opt/ssl/2015/sha2/gd_bundle.crt

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
            nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
            downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

</VirtualHost>
```

This is my ports.conf file :

```
Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
      Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

#### I have created all the required soft links as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally made it to work.

> I am posting this so that others facing the same issue may get help.

I just ***avoided the Virtual Host Tag*** with the internal IP of the server and managed to write a better Regular Expression in the RewriteRule

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass /Service http://localhost:8080/Service
    ProxyPassReverse /Service http://localhost:8080/Service





    LogLevel debug
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


    ServerName server.com

    RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on

    RewriteRule ^((?!/Service).)*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

</VirtualHost>
```

> So now, my */etc/apache2/sites-available/site.conf* file contains only one virtual tag.

I have written the expression so that all the request which contains Service need not redirect to https, and i have given the proxyPass for that also.

#### This solved my Issue

If any one has a better solution then your answers are also welcome